# What is the default BIOS password for Sony VAIO laptop

Tags: bios, passwords, sony-vaio

My laptop **(model: VGN-CR32G)** got crashed and it is not booting.

When I try to look into the BIOS settings, it is asking for password.

Is there any default Bios password available for all Sony VAIO laptops?

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: I remember from older desktops that there was often a switch on the motherboard to reset/disable the password. Also, leaving out the motherboard battery for a few weeks helped (but you lose all BIOS settings!) I have no idea if these kinds of tricks still work with modern laptops.

Comment: *Weeks!?* Minutes should be plenty enough.

Answer (score 2):

There would be no password unless somebody put a password on your BIOS, if it was previously owned contact the previous owner for the password, other than that you should check with anybody who has been on your computer to see if they set the password.

Sorry to tell you this but "default passwords" on BIOS are always blank.

Comment: When I enter a blank password it shows, "Error: Invalid password" and asks "Enter one time password" :(

Comment: I gathered that from your first post, which is why you refer to my first 3 lines of text.

Answer (score 0):

the only thing you could do is to reset your BIOS. To do so you need to open your laptop/ pc and go looking for a small flat silver battery your motherboard somewhere around your ram slots most of the time it's in the middle of the pc. for the laptop it's different story. this is located either under the batter of the laptop or it's around the pci slots.

You can also google the words 'How to reset the BIOS'